# Calculate the state vector of planets and moons

Tags: orbital-mechanics, planet

What is the efficient way to calculate the state vector of planets and moons?

The coordinate system for planets would be with center in Solar System Baricenter,
for Moon- with center in Earth and in Solar System Baricenter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of JPL kernels (`de430.bsp`) and python `jplephem` package worked for me.

Compared with the JPL Horizons, results are the same.

```
from jplephem.spk import SPK
kernel = SPK.open('de430.bsp')

position = kernel[0,3].compute(2457061.666666667)

print(position)
```